# Wifi hotspot C#

Tags: c#, wifi, hotspot

Как программно раздать wifi ( на win10 без netsh команд) средствами C#?. Посоветуйте библиотеку, возможно ли это осуществить с помощью библиотеки simplewifi? Спасибо.

Comment: Два варианта: Native WiFi (Hosted Network) and Legacy Soft AP на WiFi Directю Библитеку можно посмотреть эту (умеет оба варианта) [WiFi Framework](https://www.btframework.com/wififramework.htm)

Comment: Хотелось бы пример кода

Comment: В библиотеке есть демки. Зачем их сюда тащить? А если имеется в виду низкоуровневый код, так там очень много кода, особенно для Soft AP.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, я посмотрю.